# manifest merging error, throws exception

Tags: android, exception, android-manifest, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to convert my app to ***Instant app***. I create the base module but my manifest giving some error. I tried a lot. Is this is a plugin error or any third party library issue which I am using?

I am attaching here my `Manifest` file of `base module` and `app module`. Please help me to resolve this issue.

[image: Exception image]

***`ManifestFileOFBaseModule:`***

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="blast.com.lovethisplace">   
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application
        android:name=".Myapplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!-- Google  api -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_server_api_key" />

        <!-- Facebook  app -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/fb_id" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.StartActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.StickerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.CameraActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ImageStickerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.GoogleSearchActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PreviewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.FullImageActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PromoteActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.EarnPromoteActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.PaidPromoteActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.FilterActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             />
        <activity android:name=".activity.HelpWebActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.AboutWebActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.TellAFriendWebActivity" />
        <service android:name=".service.GPSTracker" />
        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider967904406680696"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities"
            />
        <!-- Fabric  api -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="@string/fabric_id" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.InvitePlaceScreen">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>`
```

**`ManfiestAppModule:`**

```
`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.blastapk">
</manifest>`
```

Thank you

Comment: can you check URL https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html and follow steps with URL https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/#0 might it help you to understand.

Comment: I see an error in the image, but it's hard to read the text. Can you include the text in your question? Thanks!

Comment: Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: @s.jain, i hope your problem has been resolve or you have file a bug to google, please confirm.

Comment: @PragatiSingh hi yes i have been resolve my issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. can you post your solution here.

Comment: @PragatiSingh  i changed the Application id in Instant app module.

Comment: That mean across application have same Application id, early you had changed it, please confirm. Thanks.