# Instant app package name

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have an app on play store with package name com.xyz.hello
Now I created instant app of same. I know pacakge name of instant app and installable app should be same.
I want to know to which module of instant app I have to change the package name to com.xyz.hello

- app module
- instantapp module
- Instant base
- Feature Module

Comment: it has same kind of problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762206/manifest-merging-error-throws-exception resolve by change `application id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution, just need to changed `applicationId` to same as of **installed app** in `build.gradle` of app module.

Comment: you can check more details at https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html

Answer (score 1):

In the instantapp samples provided by google they do not specify a separate AndroidManifest for the instant app module. Given this I think it will have the same package as specified in the installed AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

App Module: You need to add a new level in the app module package name, like "app". So it will change from "com.xyz.hello" to "com.xyz.hello.app".

Instant App Module: You don't need to set any package name to this module, since it doesn't have a manifest.

Base Module: The base module package name needs to be assigned as the old app's module package name, in this case "com.xyz.hello".

Feature Module: The package names for the feature modules should be assigned one level bellow the base module package name, like "com.xyz.hello.feature"